# Need help for .htaccess from OOP php to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I shifted to CodeIgntier from OOP php and there are lot of links which are not working, for example this old link

http://www.flowersentiments.com/Occassional-Special/29/Birthday/122/

should actually be redirected to

http://www.flowersentiments.com/products/Occassional/29/Birthday-Gifts/122/

I have tried all methods to redirect it using .htaccess. but It just doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: "Tried all methods"? Such as? "Doesn't work?" What errors do you get?

Comment: @andy - i tried all sort .htaccess tricks to work it out, but the issue was i was putting rewrite rule after codeIgniter .htaccess and that's what was causing all trouble. Thank you for the reply. It has worked now.

Comment: Well, if you've tried *all* methods, what more is there to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in **your document root**, you need to add your redirect rules **before** any of the other rules that yo uhave there for CodeIgniter:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Occassional-Special/([0-9]+)/Birthday/([0-9]+)/$ /products/Occassional/$1/Birthday-Gifts/$2/ [L,R=301]
```

You'll need to do the same thing (or something similar) for all of your other broken links.

Comment: Hi - Thank you, it worked. i put this line of code at the top of .htaccess and it worked. Thank you again :)

Comment: @imran yeah, you need to put it **before** your other rules.